# How to implement functionality like Facebook "New Story" feature?

Tags: android, android-intent, push-notification, android-service

I want to implement below functionality in my app.

[image]

**How can i do this?**

I have 2 ways in my mind :

1. Get total post count from **webservice** after every 1 minute or some time.
    But for that I need to run one **`Thread`** continuously in background so may be **performance issue** will arise.(Battery performance)
2. Can I do this functionality with `Notification` service?

or If any one have another Idea please suggest me.

Comment: https://github.com/lawloretienne/QuickReturn

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be good idea to do it with `push notification`. You can set flag in push notification and filter it according to your need.

create `Broadcast` which will be called when you receive `notification` of perticular flag.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("newStory");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

on that broadcast receive method show that `Image` or `Layout`.

```
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e("receiver", "Got message: ");
        //show new story image
    }
};
```

In `onResume()` register your `Broadcast`.

```
registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter("newStory"));
```

In `onPause()` unregister it.

```
unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
```

Comment: Ok I also thing for this way.

Comment: Can you please me tell me about performance of process. Which is better for performance? Push Notification or calling webservice after every 1 minute?